# How can I provide an instance of a certain script to all scripts that need it?

Tags: unity, c#

## Problem

Whenever a player is added to the game (in the form of the server instantiating a player Game Object with a `Player` component), I want to provide it to every script that needs a reference; in other words, dependency injection.

## Potential Solutions

I thought I'd create an `IPlayerRequester` interface and have the `Player` script look up all implementing scripts on the client when it's created, but Unity has no interface-searching equivalent of `FindObjectsOfType<>()`.

## More Info

The game is multiplayer, where 1 player is the host — a client *and* the server — that is joined by other clients.

I'm using [Mirror](https://mirror-networking.com/).

When a new client is added, the `Player` script's (that was just spawned) callback `OnStartLocalPlayer()` is invoked, and so far, that's the only way I've found to access the local environment.

But because this is the same `Player` that I'm trying to inject into requesting scripts, I can't just raise an event in that method, so that's out.

---

What would be a good solution here?

Comment: Unfortunately I've run into this problem a few times myself. Unity really doesn't have a good solution for this. You can get all objects that implement an interface from Resources but this will also include prefabs and can open you up to some horrifying bugs.

Comment: Depending on how many interfaces you have and if one GO can have only one interface, you could tag them and use GameObject.FindWithTag().

Comment: @Zibelas Sadly, given that I'm doing this to lessen dependency and clean up the code, that sounds like it half-defeats the purpose.

Comment: Addition to 2), what about a dictionary with <InterfaceName, List>? At least you don't need to create a new list for each new interface though you still have your singleton

Comment: You can create a class or abstract class and implement your interface, and inherit from it, but than you wouldn't be able to inherit from multiple of your interfaces. FindObjectsOfType works with classes and abstract classes.

You can avoid using FindObjectsOfType<Monobehaviour>() by keeping a list, adding removing on spawn and destroy. And filter that list. That might give you some performance benefit.

Comment: Honestly the only way I think you could do this would be to use abstract classes instead of interfaces. Basically have the default awake function register the subclass object with some singleton Manager class you can query for all interfaces. You could either do one per type using generics, or if you want to get crazy you can mix in @Zibelas solution and have a single singleton that stores all registered interfaces in a dictionary.

Comment: Also is it safe to assume that only MonoBehaviour classes implement the interfaces or could it be anything>

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson Only `MonoBehaviour` classes, I think. I'm working on the solution proposed by @Zibelas, but it's a little more complicated than that. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944394/7151327) is the closest I've found to a solution.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about why you need this in your game? There might be more elegant solutions available for that root problem.

Comment: @DMGregory Dependency injection. Whenever a player joins the game, a Player Game Object is created. That Player will look up every object on the client that has implemented `IPlayerRequester` and call its (mandatory) `AssignPlayer()` function, passing itself.

Comment: That sounds like something we could tackle with an OnLocalPlayerSpawn event, observer pattern style, without the search cost of finding interface implementations. Want to edit your question to ask "How can I provide a player instance to all scripts that need it" so we can suggest answers that aren't limited to searching by interface?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, I'll do that now. It just occurred to me I could maybe use Runtime Sets, [as described by Ryan Hipple](https://youtu.be/raQ3iHhE_Kk?t=2394), but I'd like to hear your solution as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a solution centered around [C# events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)? You could create a static event `Player.Created` and have any object subscribe to it which needs to know when a new player is created.

Comment: @Philipp That's what I tried a short while ago. The problem is, the script that creates the player — the Network Manager — runs on the server. In other words, the clients that connect to it will not see the PlayerAdded event raised.

Comment: So this is a client-server multiplayer game? That changes the question quite a lot. You might want to update it with more details for how your networking works. (note that there are several ways to do multiplayer in Unity)

Comment: @Philipp Done; I edited it.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a List of players:

```
List<Player> players;
```

and use it for a group them all and iterate with a loop to apply them some operations.
can play with it + the constructor to setting up all the stuff.

if it doesn't work u got delegates + events (a bit more advanced)

(Im not Unity dev but hope it helps)

Comment: The explanation's not entirely clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: you must know C#  programming.